# Как совместить иерархию и наследование таблиц в PostgreSQL?

Tags: наследование, архитектура, база-данных, postgresql

PostgreSQL реализует наследование таблиц. К примеру, можно создать таблицу *places* (географические объекты) и несколько таблиц, которые будут наследовать все ее колонки. Допустим, это будут таблицы для информации о городах (*cities*), реках (*rivers*) и озерах (*lakes*):

```
CREATE TABLE places (id, name, latitude, longitude, altitude);
CREATE TABLE cities (population) INHERITS (places);
CREATE TABLE rivers (lenght) INHERITS (places);
CREATE TABLE lakes  (maxdepth, volume) INHERITS (places);
```

Теперь допустим, что мы хотим хранить в базе данных информацию книгах, посвященных этим объектам. Взаимоотношение между объектом и книгами - *один-к-многим*. Как это можно сделать, если у нас данные фактически находятся в таблицах-потомках и при этом уникальность ключей действует только в пределах одной таблицы?

UPD. Никак. Такая логика работы в PostgreSQL не предполагается.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант — не использовать наследование и перейти к традиционному `cities (place_id REFERENCES places.id, population)` и выборке с JOIN'ами. Менее красиво-удобно, зато быстро и надежно.

Как другой вариант — раз PostgreSQL не хочет обеспечивать целостность ключами, то обеспечить целостность триггерами или правилами. Можно использовать наследование, но вставки и обновления будут медленнее.

Answer (score 0):

Ну триггеры/ключи можно использовать, конечно, для проверки целостности, либо можно партицировать таблицу с книгами, повесив в качестве check, например, непересечение по жанру. Соответственно, внешние ключи можно назначить от партиции к партиции. 
[Здесь на русском можно про наследование таблиц немного почитать еще](http://langtoday.com/?p=319)